# jQuery - prevent default behavior when href="#" is clicked (no class or id)

Tags: jquery

I have an existing script that needs to be updated. It contains a lot of links structured like so:

```
<a href="#" onclick="showDialog();return false;">someText</a>

function showDialog(){
$("#modal").dialog("open");
return false;
}
```

Some  have classes or id's, some not
Almost all open a jQuery dialog (moodal)
I need to stop the default scroll to top behavior as it causes intermittant issues with the dialog box opening above the viewport.

I'd like to use preventDefault but not sure what the best way to use it would be when no class or id is present.

The point of this question is to fix the issue without adding classes or changing the link structure. I need a solution that works with the link as they are coded in the existing script.

Comment: Try `$('a[href="#"]').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();})`

Comment: Wouldn't the `return false` in the onclick attribute already accomplish this?

Comment: This worked. You'd think but in Chrome the return false was not stopping the scroll to top. The other solutions provided did not answer my question. I did not want to re-code hundreds of links.

Comment: put your code in an answer so I can accept it as a solution

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use javascript:void(null); as the href?

```
<a href="javascript:void(null);" onclick="showDialog(); return false;">SomeText</a>
```

Comment: Or even better: why do you use inline js when using jQuery?

Comment: Because he is calling his showDialog function inline too.

Comment: You don't need the `void` if you have `return false`. You don't need the `return false` if you have the `void`. This solution is a hack.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery I would restructure it something like this...

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="dialog-link">Text</a>
```

JS

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dialog-link').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#modal").dialog("open");
    });
});
</script>
```

The `return false` is not required when using `preventDefault`.